# If I search for a Miracle and put it in my hand, can I cast it for its Miracle cost?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Lets say I use [Mystical Teachings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=111058) to grab [Thunderous Wrath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvI66.jpg) out of my library during my upkeep and put it in my hand.  Can I then cast Thunderous Wrath for its Miracle cost?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No.** The card changes zones but is never *drawn* by you.

> 120.5. If an effect moves cards from a player’s library to that player’s hand without using the word
>   “draw,” the player has not drawn those cards. This makes a difference for abilities that trigger on
>   drawing cards and effects that replace card draws, as well as if the player’s library is empty.

This means you can't cast the cards you tutor directly into your hand by paying their miracle cost.

It does, however, mean that any cards you tutor up with Mystical Teachings won't count towards your "first card drawn this turn" -- so you could use Teachings on your upkeep and still cast a miracle card you drew naturally, for example.

If you want to cast miracle cards with tutors, use ones that put cards on top of your library, like [Mystical Tutor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194976) and [Liliana Vess](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205961).

Comment: I have a subsidiary question, seeing as you're "in the zone" right now - suppose I draw multiple cards in my upkeep, say by, I don't know, turning a Fathom Seer face up.  I put them in my hand and then try to cast one for its Miracle cost.  Presumably only one of them was "the first card drawn this turn" - have I broken the rules by not showing my opponent that the first card I drew was a Miracle, as I drew it?

Comment: @thesunneversets I think that's a separate question. The short answer is your draw them one at a time. "120.2. Cards may only be drawn one at a time. If a player is instructed to draw multiple cards, that player performs that many individual card draws." I haven't seen the newest MTR, but my assumption in tournament play is that judges won't let you miracle-cast a card if you've already let it touch your other hand cards.

Comment: Mm, it is a different question.  Bad news for people like me, whose instinct I suspect when told to "draw 3 cards" is to grab 3 off the top of the deck, add them to my hand and then look at them... I guess it's only the first card you ever have to be careful about though, and then only if there are Miracles in the deck!